# Typescript noImplicitAny and noImplicitReturns not working as expected

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I have added the "noImplicitAny" and "noImplicitReturns" to my Typescript tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target":"es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals":true,
        "out": "dist/js/main.js"
    }
}
```

I expected that the following code would generate errors, or at least warnings:

```
private randomMove() {  // no return type but no warning :(
    let o = 3;          // no type for o but no warning :(
}
```

The "noUnusedLocals" IS working.

Is this how it's supposed to work, am I missing something?
Is it possible to have Visual Studio Code generate warnings when you don't specify types / return types?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You misunderstood what those flags mean.

**noImplicitAny**:

> Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied any type.

This isn't the case in your example because the compiler infers that the type of `o` is `number`, you should get the error if you do:

```
let o;
```

**noImplicitReturns**:

> Report error when not all code paths in function return a value.

Your function might not need to return at all, but doing this:

```
function fn(a: number): boolean {
    if (a > 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Should result in a compilation error.

No, there's no way (that I'm aware of) that will cause the compiler to error if a function doesn't include a return type.
That's because:

1. The compiler can infer the return type itself most of the time
2. What if your function doesn't return? It would be way too verbose for a lot of people to need to annotate each function with `: void`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :) I'd still like a warning / scribbly line in my code when I omit the type! That's why I use Typescript to begin with :)

Comment: Why? If the compiler can infer that itself, why would you want to make it mandatory?

Comment: Maybe not mandatory but at least give off a warning or squiggly line. The main reason for using Typescript instead of Javascript is that types are checked... I mean, javascript also infers the type....

Comment: Javascript doesn't infer the type, it has a value and it tries to do what the lines of code tells it to, it just might end up throwing an error. As for typescript, it has types, and it checks that everything is fine, but if it can infer the return type of a function then what benefit do you get of specifying it anyhow?

Comment: But javascript HAS data types.... it determines the type of the variable when you put something in it... var greeting = "hi" makes greeting a string. My point is that this happens invisibly, while in Typescript you can specify it yourself to make sure only the right values can ever get passed in.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can use `.compilerOptions.checkJs: true` in `jsconfig.json` to check for errors in JS files.

Comment: very nice one. Thank you.

Comment: @Kokodoko JS has _runtime_ types. Typescript has _compile-time_ types. That's the big difference. It's still totally ok to leave the type out so long as the compiler can infer the type. But it's still your choice, of course.

Comment: @Clonkex I think what Kokodoko is trying to say (and I agree), is that they would prefer that we could ensure that typescript transpiler does not incorrectly infer a type.